# solve the wireless PC

Tags: wireless-networking

A customer complains that the network connection on their laptop is intermittent. The customer states that they are using a wireless PC card for network connectivity, and believes that the laptop may be too far from the wireless access point. However, he does not know where the wireless access point is located.

What should I tell the customer?

Comment: What is the current signal strength.  Where is your modem located.  But I fear this question will lead to alot of opinion-based answers.

Comment: Do you have access to the customer location? You can do a site survey if you have access.

Answer (score 1):

If the Windows signal strength gauge displays only 1 or 2 bars, the customer's suspicions may be correct.

[image]

If he is in a location where he cannot see the wireless access point, he'll need to move the system around and see how the signal bars change.